# VMware ESXI - External PCI Ethernet Card

Tags: vmware-esxi, pfsense, 10gbethernet, pci

I have a beast of a home server and don’t fancy purchasing another device just to learn PFSense on my network. My server only has 1 Ethernet port, I have an external PCI card I bought off from amazon but it looks like VMWare ESXI doesn’t recognise it. (It was cheap & cheerful). I cant seem to find a list of compatible PCI External Eth cards. Preferably I would go for 1or10gb ports with a minimum of 3/4.

I’m struggling to understand or find what to buy and how to get it to work.

Any suggestions!

Thanks all!
Louis

Answer (score 1):

You can search the [VMware Compatibility Guide](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php) for compatible hardware. Just type the NIC or chip/product ID into the searchbox and get a list of supported releases. You will find a lot of (almost only) enterprise hardware there, because it makes no sense to support cheap (and probably crappy) chips in a product targetting the enterprise segment.

So I would search for older and/or used enterprise stuff. Like the Intel NC364Ts (4x Gbit), for example. It's cheap (<30$), reliable, avaiable on amazon, perfectly supported and avaible in almosty any falvor - hpe, intel, ibm, dell, you name it.

(This is just an example, not a advertisement - and a report that those work perfectly fine in 6.7U3)